# Object-based content management system

Tags: cms

I remember hearing within the last year or two about a content management system either being released or developed that was centralized around product/item information. I'm aware that there are several CMSes that have this capability, but this particular one was built specifically for that task. Also, I remember it winning some sort of award or recognition for upcoming software products.

However, I can't for the life of me remember what this CMS was called or who was developing it.

Does anyone know what package I'm talking about?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "product/item information?" Normally I'd read that as an e-commerce application, but then you'd probably have just said that if so.

Comment: I think the best example to similarity I can give is [gdgt](http://gdgt.com/). It's not an e-commerce website, it's purely informational, and it has community-oriented elements. If you look at [a product specs page](http://gdgt.com/logitech/mx/revolution/specs/), you can see categorized specifications that can be used for comparisons.

Comment: @AdamMaras : how about making an answer with that? ;)

Comment: @OlivierPons Because I'm looking for a specific software package that I can reuse. gdgt is just a good example of what *could* be done with such a package.

Answer (score 4):

I know [Zope](http://www.zope.org/) is an application server written in python that is centered around fully object oriented model

[Plone](http://plone.org/) is a CMS built upon Zope that uses this object oriented architecture to take full advantage of the underlying architecture for defining it's content types.

I've even read about an extension that can take an UML model definition (a class diagram for sure) and produce a full Plone content type definition out of it.

Comment: That's a great answer, but alas, not the one I'm looking for. Thank you anyway for trying. +1 as I will look into this regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be [OneSource](http://www.apsiva.com/r5/product-information/management/product-information-management-software.htm)? This was just from a Google.

Comment: No, I don't believe it was a commercial software package. If memory serves, it was something more open, like WordPress or Django.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [Magneto](http://www.magnetocommerce.com) or one of the others [listed here](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/01/8-interesting-cms-for-e-commerce.html)?

Comment: No, it wasn't an e-Commerce package.